Python Tkinter with OOP. How to define function for changing button attributes?
I am learning Object Oriented Programming for Python using Tkinter.
I want to create a Class for each type of widgets (right now considering only Buttons).
I am passing the Button class to my main App class.
Below is the code I have so far:
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Buttons:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def buttons(self,text,width,cmd,col,row):
        self.text = text
        self.width = width
        self.cmd = cmd
        self.col = col
        self.row = row
        ttk.Button(text=self.text, width=self.width, command=self.cmd).grid(column=self.col,row=self.row)

class App(tk.Tk, Buttons):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry('100x100')
        self.resizable(0,0)
        b1 = self.buttons('Btn1',10,lambda: changeButton(),0,0)
        b2 = self.buttons('Btn2',10,lambda: changeButton(),0,1)
        self.mainloop()
        
# where should I place this function? How can I change button attributes?
def changeButton(self):
    b1['text'] = 'Done'   # If button 1 pressed
    b2['text'] = 'OKAY'   # If button 2 pressed

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = App()

I have two questions -

Where should I place the function 'changeButton()' and why?
If I have 2 buttons, and when pressed, if they should change their texts to something else; is it possible to do that via a single function? Or should there be a 2 functions?

Thank you
When I try the above code, I get the error:
line 20, in <lambda>  
    b1 = self.buttons('Btn1',10,lambda: changeButton(),0,0)
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: changeButton() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'


On line 25,  the indentation def changeButton(self) should be inside  class App(tk.Tk, Buttons):

There are many ways to perform this task, I've added comments inside the code for convenience reasons.
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class MyButton(ttk.Button):
    def __init__(self, text, width, cmd, col, row):
        super().__init__()
        self.textvar = tk.StringVar()  # create a StringVar object
        self.textvar.set(text)  # set the value of the StringVar object
        self.config(textvariable=self.textvar, width=width)
        self.grid(column=col,row=row)
        self.bind('<Button-1>', cmd)  # binding the cmd function with the Mouse '<Button-1>' event to MyButton object


class App(tk.Tk, MyButton):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry('100x100')
        self.resizable(0,0)
        MyButton('Btn1', 10, changeButton, 0, 0)
        MyButton('Btn2', 10, changeButton, 0, 1)
        self.mainloop()


# where should I place this function? How can I change button attributes?
def changeButton(event):
    """
    event is the Mouse '<Button-1>' event object containing information about the event
    event.widget is the MyButton object that generated the event
    event.widget.textvar is the StringVar object of the MyButton object
    event.widget.textvar.get() returns the value of the StringVar object
    event.widget.textvar.set() sets the value of the StringVar object

    print(dir(event)) to see all the attributes of the event object
    """
    text = (
        'Done' if event.widget.textvar.get() == 'Btn1' else
        'OKAY' if event.widget.textvar.get() == 'Btn2' else
        'Btn1' if event.widget.textvar.get() == 'Done' else
        'Btn2'
    )
    event.widget.textvar.set(text)


if __name__=="__main__":
    app = App()


wow! This is awesome. I will need to study your code and understand it. Thank you very much!

@ranjitmore someone has voted down my answer, if you vote up and accept my answer, it could help others who might think now the answer was not helpful.

Hi...your answer is helpful. But I am not able to upvote it. It says I need atleast a 15 reputation. Sorry about that.

@ranjitmore You can accept the answer if it is useful!
